# What are the required versions when migrating Sonar from 2.7 to 4.0

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to migrate Sonar from version 2.7 to 4.0 and would like to know the required versions needed for this migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, then the answer is: you don't need any specific versions of SonarQube, just download the version you want (so in your case 4.0) and follow the [upgrade guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading), and everything will be fine.